# MySQL DISTINCT call counts by state

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, distinct

I'm trying to get the unique call counts (no dupe calls) by state. For example...

```
MO  249
OK  220
CA  216
TX  190
KS  158
```

The following works (no errors), but it's not removing the dupes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CallFrom, FromState, count(*) AS cnt
FROM `calls`
WHERE DateCreated >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 YEAR AND
(CallTo = '+15555555555' OR CallTo = '+15555555556' )
GROUP BY FromState
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: The following 'calls' table example was requested...

```
Index   CallTo          CallFrom    FromState
1       +15555555555    18166283100 MO
2       +15555555556    13307059600 OH
3       +15555555555    17722631600 FL
4       +15555555556    16173024800 MA
5       +15555555556    16173024800 MA
6       +15555555556    16175025500 MA
```

Just realized I forgot to include the DateCreated column, but like I said, everything is working except for deduplicating. The output for this example would be...

```
MA  2
MO  1
OH  1
FL  1
```

Comment: What are dupes in your case ?

Comment: Duplicate CallFroms. It that what you're asking? Multiple calls from the same person.

Comment: That would be awesome if you can provide input samples

Comment: I update my post to include what I think you're asking for. Let me know if I'm wrong about this.

Comment: just remove `CallFrom` from your `SELECT`

Comment: As far as I can see you're expecting the wrong output. It should be `3` for MA. There are 3 calls for that state. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4536b90f69bf1c6ecfd41d7a2f216779 . If you group by the  CallFrom field as well then the MA entries get split in two since there are 2 different numbers. There were 2 calls from one number, and 1 call from another. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc4772272be78f0be6bce6b57f79a4d1 .

Comment: It's unclear why you think the output should be as it is. What do you mean by "de-duplicating", exactly? It's also unclear what you think DISTINCT would add in this situation? the rows will always be distinct, since you're grouping.

Comment: Maybe you just want this (a distinct list of number/state combos, without the grouping and counting): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7274f014a962300ebe1b66a64af3c255 ? It's really not clear. That's how you'd use "DISTINCT" in this scenario, and that's how you'd get a unique list of numbers (i.e. no "duplicates"). If it's not that, you're going to have to explain your logic in more detail.

Comment: @ADyson, I'm trying to remove duplicate CallFrom calls. Currently, it's showing 3 calls from MA, but I want it to show 2 calls because of the 3 calls, 2 are duplicates.

Comment: trouble with describing something as "removing" is that queries don't remove things, they select things. Better to describe in terms of what you want to include, if you can. I think I finally figured out what you mean - see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wording is not very clear, but I think you're saying you want to count how many unique CallFrom numbers occurred in each state. There may be better ways to do this, but this will work. First it builds a list of unique CallFrom/State combinations, and then it groups and counts on that list, instead of on the raw data:

```
SELECT FromState, COUNT(*) 
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT CallFrom, FromState 
  FROM `calls` 
  WHERE 
    (CallTo = '+15555555555' OR CallTo = '+15555555556' )
  ) c 
GROUP BY FromState
```

Demo: 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d057e3482ec9d5ad4519e58056232e58

Comment: Okay, this keeps bugging me. You said, "you want to count how many unique CallFrom numbers occurred in each state."

My first sentence was, "I'm trying to get the unique call counts (no dupe calls) by state."

To avoid this faux pas the future, what's the difference?

Comment: Sorry, you did actually say that, it's true. I think it's the latter parts of the question near the sample data regarding "deduplicating" etc. that I was concentrating on and had started to confuse me. Also your description didn't fully clarify what a "dupe call" was, exactly. There could be more than one way to define that, than just receiving a call from the same number twice. But yeah I could have cottoned on to it quicker.